# Business Intelligence & Analytics

Tags: business-intelligence

How many records should we display in Report when there are multiple tables with different relationship mapping is present?

Suppose table Employees has 100 Records
table Department has 35 Records
table Region has 10 Records

Employee(0) - Region(N) - (0-N) Relationship
Employee(0) - Department(N) - (0-N) Relationship

If report asks for how many employees work for a particular department which lies in particular region, how many records should we show in a report?

Answer (score 0):

The relationships you provided don't suggest that there is a direct relationship between Department and Region. If this can be inferred by the joins through Employee, and you are grouping by Department and Region in order to do a count on Employee, you will have as many records as there are departments and regions.

For example, this SQL would provide the count by region and department (a complete guess at table and column names).

```
select region.name, department.name, count(distinct employee.id)
from employee left join region on employee.region_id = region.id
              left join department on employee.department_id = department.id
group by region.name, department.name;
```

Without knowing the cardinality of Department to Region (since it's not a relational join) we can't say, but if it was N Departments to 1 Region, you'll have 35 records returned, one for each Department.